# Django: select_related() and memory usage

Tags: django, memory, django-select-related

I am working on an API, and I have a question. I was looking into the usage of `select_related()`, in order to save myself some database queries, and indeed it does help in reducing the amount of database queries performed, on the expense of bigger and more complex queries.

My question is, does using `select_related()` cause heavier memory usage? Running some experiments I noticed that indeed this is the case, but I'm wondering why. Regardless of whether I use `select_related()`, the response will contain the exact same data, so why does the use of `select_related()` cause more memory to be used?

Is it because of caching? Maybe separate data objects are used to cache the same model instances? I don't know what else to think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a tradeoff. It takes time to send a query to the database, the database to prepare results, and then send those results back. `select_related` works off the principle that the most expensive part of this process is the request and response cycle, not the actual query, so it allows you to combine what would otherwise have been distinct queries into just one so there's only one request and response instead of multiple.

However, if your database server is under-powered (not enough RAM, processing power, etc.), the larger query could actually end up taking longer than the request and response cycle. If that's the case, you probably need to upgrade the server, though, rather than not use `select_related`.

The rule of thumb is that if you need related data, you use `select_related`. If it's not actually faster, then that's a sign that you need to optimize your database.

**UPDATE** (adding more explanation)

Querying a database actually involves multiple steps:

1. Application generates the query (negligible)
2. Query is sent to the database server (milliseconds to seconds)
3. Database processes the query (milliseconds to seconds)
4. Query results are sent back to application (milliseconds to seconds)

In a well-tuned environment (sufficient server resources, fast connections) the entire process is finished in mere milliseconds. However, steps 2 and 4, still usually take more time overall than step 3. This is why it makes more sense to send fewer more complex queries than multiple simpler queries: the bottleneck is most usually the transport layer not the processing.

However, a poorly optimized database, on an under-powered machine with large and complex tables could take a very long time to run the query, becoming the bottleneck. That would end up negating the decrease in time gained from sending one complex query instead of multiple simpler ones, i.e. the database would have responded quicker to the simpler queries and the entire process would have taken less net time.

Nevertheless, if this is the case, the proper response is to fix the database-side: optimize the database and its configuration, add more server resources, etc., rather than reverting to sending multiple simple queries instead.

Comment: Chris, thanks for the response. One follow-up question; You mention: _if your database server is under-powered the larger query could actually end up taking longer than the request and response cycle_. What is the reason that this happens? How does a larger query take longer that the request/response cycle? And how is more memory eaten-up by the larger query? Thank you :)

Comment: By "larger" query, I mean one that is more complex (involving joins and such), not necessarily the textual length of the actual query. The database must then proceed to do a lot of extra work selecting data from multiple sources and stitching it all together. Additionally, if these tables have many columns and/or rows, that can add to the time and processing involved. If the system running the DB has sufficient resources, it shouldn't take more than a few milliseconds, though. However, if the system is under-powered, leading to memory overflow and paging, it could take much more time.